# Exclude text from search results preview snippet?

Tags: seo, search-engine, screen-readers

I've implemented a "Skip to Content" link on my site and hidden it off screen (except when `:focus`ed). However, I've noticed on some pages where I haven't explicitly defined a meta description, Google picks up "Skip to Content" for its preview snippet in search results.

Is there a way to format or mark text that shouldn't be used in a search snippet? My case is a skip to content link, but I can imagine other similar needs. However, in this case, it must remain accessible (so no `display:none`, etc.).

I supposed what I'm looking for is some version of `rel="nofollow"` but for the text and not just the link.

---

tl;dr: "Skip to content" link appears in search snippets. That's not desired.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is such a way for the general Google search.

Google allows customers of their *Google Search Appliance* and *Google Mini* products to state which content should be ignored for the search by using `googleoff` and `googleon` in HTML comments; see [Excluding Unwanted Text from the Index](https://developers.google.com/search-appliance/documentation/46/admin_crawl/Preparing#pagepart). **But** this doesn't work for the public Google search, of course.

---

I think the bestway  to try to prevent that problem would be to use a `meta` `description`: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=79812

```
<meta name="description" content="A description of the page" />
```

Comment: I use the meta description whenever I can, but this being a WordPress site, there are some things I wanted indexed—such as category archives—that I don't really want to spend the time writing descriptions for. I suppose I could make a generic "This page lists articles about X" description, but that feels unsatisfactory.

Comment: Google help link: https://support.google.com/gsa/answer/6329153?hl=en#57a1e30a-63b2-4470-86a5-94a6c06912be

Answer (score 1):

As of ~2021, you can exclude text from being included in a Google snippet.  You can use a `data-nosnippet` html tag on `div`, `span`, or `section` elements.  It looks like this:

```
<div>Show this
<span data-nosnippet>Never show this in the snippet, but otherwise display it normally</span>
</div>
```

Documentation at https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/robots-meta-tag#data-nosnippet-attr

Answer (score 0):

> it must remain accessible (so no display:none, etc.)

Well, if you're OK with using JavaScript, you can still use `style="display:none"` in your div or span tag and add the following to your JS file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.getElementById('skip').style.display = "block";

    //Or shorter with jQuery
    $('#skip').show(); //Alternatively: fadeIn()
});
```